# Rails routing :except question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, except

I'm trying to make a simple blog with a *posts* controller route to the root url rather than localhost/posts/:id.

I added the following to my routes file...

```
match '/:id', :to => 'posts#show', :as => 'post'
```

Which worked well enough. It has since broken my search route.

```
match 'search/:q', :to => 'posts#query', :as => 'search'
```

It looks like rails is trying to find a post with the id of my search query. Is there a way of doing something like the following to get the routes file to assume everything after the root url is a post id EXECPT anything starting with 'search'?

```
match '/:id', :to => 'posts#show', :as => 'post', :except => 'search'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails parses your routes from the top down and stops at the first match. I would put your `match '/:id'...` line below all your other routes.